# How I can connect a menu link with a LINK that exists in an another menu link?

Tags: routes, navigation

I have a menu link `menulink2` that when clicked goes to `admin/bla/blabla`. I have also another menu link `menulink1` that do not go nowhere. Now I want `menulink1` when clicked to go on the same link that `menulink2` goes... Any ideas?? I suppose it will be with menu_alter..

Comment: What do you mean by 'connect', and why, exactly, simply setting the same address is not enougH?

Comment: yes how i can do it programmatically.... The menulink2 has a link that change per user so i want it to take the absolute link that the menulink2 would take

Comment: "a link that change per user " - **how** does it change per user? By what means?

Comment: I have a menu and every user when press the button menulink2 see something according to his uid... I want the menulink1 which is another button on my menu to show on the same links.

Comment: "see something according to his uid" - what mechanism was used to implement this?